# complexity of deciding membership of tail sigma-field

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be the Cantor space equipped with the standard product topology (so $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\aleph_0}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel algebra associated with the topology generated by cylinder sets of the form $B_x^n=\{y: x_k=y_k, \forall k\leq n\}$). Let $X_n:\Omega\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ be the projection map. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the tail-sigma algebra, i.e.~$\mathcal{T}=\bigcap_n^\infty\mathcal{G}_n$ where $\mathcal{G}_n=\sigma\{X_m: m\geq n\}$. I am curious to know if there is a way of deciding whether a set in $\mathcal{F}$ is a tail event. I know, for instance, that all sets of sequences that are identical in the limit are tail events (e.g.~$\{\omega: \lim_nX_n(\omega)=p\}$), but these are sufficient conditions. In particular, is there any computability-theoretic result about how complex a tail-sigma algebra is in general for standard Borel space?

Comment: I'm not sure you're getting any other description of the tail $\sigma$-algebra than "it consists of all the measurable events which depend only on the last infinitely many indices." So, for instance, the set of sequences, which have $1$'s infinitely often is tail-measurable, the set of sequences which start repeating a pattern after a certain point is measurable, and so on. Curiously, interpreting elements of $\Omega$ as elements of $[0,1]$ in base $2$ decimal expansion, this last one implies that whether or not an element is rational is tail measurable.

Comment: On the other hand, deciding whether an element is larger than $\frac{1}{2}$ *isn't*.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I see. I guess I was curious about this question partly because of this paper by Blackwell on a non-measurable set wrt the tail-sigma field (https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.lnms/1215453560). It makes sense that a set constructed from a free ultrafilter is not a tail event, but the fact that there is a specific paper on its construction suggests we don't have a firm grasp on what does and does not belong to the tail field. Hence I was wondering if there is any literature that explores this question.